# Lapsed Patent outside of US

Tags: prior-art, design

If there is a company in the US wanting to patent a design, but there is a "Lapsed" Australian patent on a similar design, can the US company pursue a patent? A similar US patent does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The Australian patent represents prior art even in the US. It doesn't matter whether or not it is lapsed. Whether the new patent application will be granted depends on how "similar" the prior art is.